# Problemas no retorno de dados ao criar um search em php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um `search.php` para meu sisteminha, até o momento está tudo OK, porém no `while` que criei para mostrar futuramente as perguntas que batem com o título pesquisado e seus respectivos links, não aparece nada na página.

Nenhum erro de SQL ou qualquer coisa, simplesmente não retorna nenhum dado.

Gostaria de uma visão mais aperfeiçoada em SQL para verificar se há algum erro abaixo na pesquisa ou na forma de exibir com o `while`.

```
<?php

            require_once("php/conexao.php");

            if (isset($_GET['search'])) {

                $textoBusca = $_GET['search'];

                $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM questoes WHERE titulo LIKE '".$textoBusca."'";

                $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $strSQL); 

                ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <div class="page-header texto-pesquisa">
                            <h2>Você buscou por "<?php echo $textoBusca; ?>"</h2>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <?php

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $artigos = $row['titulo'];


                    ?>

                            <p><?php echo $artigos; ?></p>


                    <?php } ?> <!-- fecha o while -->
                     </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

        <?php } ?> <!-- Fecha o IF -->
```

Comment: A busca no banco retorna algum registro?

Comment: Troca `LIKE '".$textoBusca."'` para `LIKE '%".$textoBusca."%'` e vê oque retorna.

Comment: Perfeito, @henriquedpereira, funcionou! Sempre tenho esses problemas com copiar o comando SQL para o PHP e imprimi-lo direito. Alguma dica? Rs

Comment: Da uma olhada na documentação para entender melhor o uso do `LIKE` = https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Opa... por segurança, seria melhor mudar a forma de como a query está montada e utilizar o [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) para evitar injections.

Answer (score 2):

Ao montar um banco de dados, precisamos de mecanismos para que se possa extrair os dados desse banco, e a forma de fazermos isso é através de consultas SQL. Uma consulta SQL nada mais é do que uma pergunta que fazemos ao banco de dados. Para que a resposta seja a contento é necessário que a pergunta seja bem feita e para nos auxiliar na hora de fazer a consulta é que nós utilizamos os operadores SQL.

> No seu caso, troque `LIKE '".$textoBusca."'` para `LIKE '%".$textoBusca."%'`

### NO ENTANTO, "PRA QUE SERVE" O OPERADOR LIKE?

Usa-se o operador LIKE em uma cláusula WHERE para procurar uma string padrão, usando o LIKE com o Sublinhado (_) e Porcentagem (%).

- `Sublinhado (_)` - Serve para marcar uma posição Específica
- `Porcentagem (%)` - Qualquer carácter a partir da posição especificada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na consulta acima, perguntamos ao banco através do SQL, quais são os registros onde a segunda letra é **U**. O `Sublinhado (_)` significa a posição da primeira letra, ou seja, não precisamos saber qual é primeira letra. Você pode mudar a posição de acordo com a sua necessidade.

**Selecionando todos os registros que iniciam com a letra J**:

```
Select * from Pessoa Where Nome LIKE 'J%';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte](http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-os-operadores-like-in-e-between-no-oracle/24687)